# How do I remove middle characters in a file name for each file in a directory

Tags: c#

How do I remove characters in the middle of each file name in a directory?

My directory is filled with files like: "Example01.1234312232.txt", "Example02.2348234324.txt", etc.

I would like to remove the ".1234312232" so it will named "Example01.txt", and do this for  every file in the directory.

Each file name will always have the same number of characters in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use

```
string fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
string newFileName = string.Format("{0}{1}",
                                   fileNameOnly.Split('.')[0],
                                   Path.GetExtension(path));
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/c891Ip)

For what it's worth, the complete code for your directory-renaming problem:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(folder))
{
    string fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
    string newFileName = string.Format("{0}{1}",
                           fileNameOnly.Split('.')[0],
                           Path.GetExtension(file));
    File.Move(file, Path.Combine(folder, newFileName));
}
```

Comment: I tried it out and without adding txt it removes the .txt leaving it as a "file", the split probably removes the .txt

Comment: @CSharpStudent: Have you looked at the "demo"-link? I'm splitting the filename without the extension, then i'm using `Path.GetExtension` and add it to the new filename. If you want to create the full path(f.e. to copy the file), you need to add the full path with the directory. Therefore you should use `Path.Combine`.

Comment: try the program, console.Writeline returns example1., or you could change the format to: string.Format("{0}.txt"

Comment: @CSharpStudent: Well, your path is not a valid path to a file. With your code you need to use the variable `file` instead of `path`.

Comment: @CSharpStudent: I wanted to leave some work for the OP, but now i've provided the rest, look above.

Comment: hmm, noticed the {0}.{1} but you beat me to it, anyway thanks for pointing out the path instead of file, my mistake

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use a regular expression replacement of

```
\.\d+
```

for an empty string `""`:

```
var str = "Example01.1234312232.txt";
var res = Regex.Replace(str, @"\.\d+", "");
Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", res);
```

Here is a [link to a demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/xmIf5K).

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the [IO.DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) class and the [GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cyf24ss.aspx) function to get the list of files.
Loop all files and do a [substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to get the string you want.
Then you call [My.Computer.Filesystem.RenameFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ce15by3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to rename the files.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
filename.Replace(filename.Substring(9, 15), ".txt")
```

You can hard code the index and length because you said the number of characters have same length.

Answer (score 0):

Use Directory.EnumerateFiles to enumerate the files, Regex.Replace to get the new name and File.Move to rename files:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class SampleSolution
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var path = @"C:\YourDirectory";
        foreach (string fileName in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path))
        {
            string changedName = Regex.Replace(fileName, @"\.\d+", string.Empty);
            if (fileName != changedName)
            {
                File.Move(fileName, changedName);    
            }
        }
    }
}
```